# Tablets being able to make calls

Tags: tablet, calls

I wonder can any of the Android tablets make calls (it's about Cellular calls, not Skype or other)?

Yeah, I am okay to have 7' or even 10' tablet near my ear and have a talk (well, or use headsets).

Having those tablets being able to make calls would make me throw the smartphone away and have the single gadget.

I know that Galaxy Tab 7' is capable doing this.

But how about Galaxy Tab 10' or Nexus 7?

Are they capable? Or is there any possibility to make them having this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Galaxy Tab 10.1 can make 2G/3G calls and calls over Wifi with Voip apps like Skype or Tango.

The Nexus 7 can only make calls over Wifi with Voip apps as I already mentioned. There would be no easy way of getting the Nexus 7 to make 2G/3G calls as it would require adding a radio to the tablet.

Comment: Galaxy Tab 10.1 can make cellular calls is that correct? HOw bout  the Galaxy Tab 2 10'?

Comment: Yes, it has a cellular radio.